# How to fix a AutomaticUrlReservationCreationFailureException when using Nancy FX Self Host

Tags: nancy, netsh

When using Nancy FX, I came across the following exception which was thrown when trying to fire up a web service: `AutomaticUrlReservationCreationFailureException`

Having looked into it in a bit more detail, I discovered that the way to fix this was to run up a cmd prompt (as an administrator), then run the following command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=DOMAIN\username
```

where

- `DOMAIN\username` is the id of the user the service will be run under
- `1234` is the port that the service will be run on

I write this here in case anyone else comes across the same issue and spends a fruitless half hour or so looking for an answer - hopefully they will find this sooner than I did!

Comment: You should format this as a question and provide your own answer to it; this will help future users, especially if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Message` of the `AutomaticUrlReservationCreationFailureException` will tell you this

```
The Nancy self host was unable to start, as no namespace reservation existed for the provided url(s).

Please either enable CreateNamespaceReservations on the HostConfiguration provided to the NancyHost, or create the reservations manually with the (elevated) command(s):

http add urlacl url=http://+:8888/nancy/ user=Everyone
http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:8888/nancy/ user=Everyone
http add urlacl url=http://+:8889/nancytoo/ user=Everyone
```

The suggested reservations is based on the base URIs that you pass into the host when you create it.

Comment: Ah yes, see I should have looked a little harder at the error message - sorry for not spotting. I'm quite unfamiliar with network configuration tools so hadn't understood what the message meant.

Thanks very much for the help in answering my question.

Comment: This step does not seem necessary if I am creating my own web server using HttpListener - just curious why this would be needed for Nancy?

Answer (score 18):

If you're creating your own NancyFx host, it may be easier for you to flag your HostConfiguration this way

```
HostConfiguration hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration()
{
    UrlReservations = new UrlReservations() { CreateAutomatically = true }
};
```

or...

```
HostConfiguration hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration();
hostConfigs.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;
```

And then finally have something like

```
NancyHost nancyHost = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://+:80"), new DefaultNancyBootstrapper(), hostConfigs);
```

Comment: Does this require the Nancy service account to have local admin privileges?

Comment: I get with tat code : 
  System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure namespace reservation
  at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.StartListener()
  at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.Start()

Comment: Ok, got it. It's because in French "Everyone" is "Tout le monde" with two spaces and that the command that Nancy launches does not protect the argument with quotes... Sot that method is not reliable for now, have to use netsh in a install program.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Nancy throws me an exception if I try to use any wildcards for the Uri(). I'm using the Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost() if that makes any difference? Anyone else get the same?

Answer (score 11):

The `AutomaticUrlReservationCreationFailureException` will also appear if you are running NancyFX from Visual Studio.

So make sure you are running as administrator in order for NancyFX to set up the underlying configurations